# CSS 'footer' div relationship to 'content' div

Tags: css, positioning, sticky-footer

I have researched this (sticky footer?) to the point of hair pulling but nothing seems to answer my problem.

Problem: I have a centred transparent wrapper div, position:relative; height:auto; with 4 divs inside position:absolute; and 3 have height fixed. They are all positioned to appear down the page. The 4th div is my transparent content div and must be able to expand height wise further down the page. My footer is also transparent, height fixed and must have a gap from the content div but move in accordance with it not the bottom of the wrapper/page.

I hope I've explained it well enough but I'm fairly new to all this so please bear that in mind.

TIA

John

Comment: Paste your code at jsFiddle.net so we can play with it ... It'll help a lot more than your description

Comment: As a rule, position: absolute is not good for page layout, as it makes the page very inflexible. Abs: pos elements are taken out of the document flow, meaning they don't play well with other element (e.g. they don't push other elements down as they grow). Show us what layout you want, and we'll suggest a better way.